# Can we have a "very strong" cone phenomenon in the Turing degrees (and a related question)?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

By Borel determinacy + Martin's cone theorem, for every countable fragment $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ there is a turing degree ${\bf c}$ such that for all ${\bf d}\ge_T{\bf c}$ we have $(\mathcal{D},{\bf c})\equiv_\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{D},{\bf d}).$ Here "$\equiv_\mathcal{A}$" denotes $\mathcal{A}$-elementary equivalence, and $(\mathcal{D},{\bf a})$ is the structure gotten from the poset of Turing degrees by adding a constant symbol naming ${\bf a}$. A key step here is the *countable completeness of the Martin filter*: we use the cone theorem to get a cone on which $\varphi$ is "stable" for each sentence $\varphi\in\mathcal{A}$, then take the intersection of these cones. This breaks down once we look at uncountable sets of infinitary sentences.

> **Question 1**: Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ that there is a Turing degree ${\bf c}$ such that for all ${\bf d}\ge_T{\bf c}$ we have $$(\mathcal{D},{\bf c})\equiv_{\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}}(\mathcal{D},{\bf d})?$$

Note that, roughly speaking, any way of associating a countable structure to a degree would have to result in isomorphic structures when applied to degrees $\ge_T{\bf c}$; for example, if ${\bf d}\ge_T{\bf c}$ then we would need to have $\mathcal{D}_{\le_T{\bf d}}\cong\mathcal{D}_{\le_T{\bf c}}$. This is a consequence of Scott's isomorphism theorem. But this doesn't actually seem that great an obstacle. *(EDIT: looks like I misjudged this, see Ted Slaman's comment below.)*

In fact, even a weaker question seems difficult (and to me this suggests that the answer to Question 1 should be negative):

> **Question 2**: Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ that there are distinct Turing degrees ${\bf a},{\bf b}$ such that $$(\mathcal{D},{\bf a})\equiv_{\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}}(\mathcal{D},{\bf b})?$$

Of course a *negative* answer to Question 2 can't be hoped for at the moment, since that would imply a negative answer to the automorphism question which is still inaccessible. However, a positive answer does seem not-too-impossible; moreover, obstacles to a simple positive answer to Q2 might lead to a negative answer to Q1.

**To clarify, Q1 is the question I'm primarily interested in; my interest in Q2 is mostly because it might help clarify Q1**. I'd also be interested in answers to the analogous questions for other degree structures *(e.g. the hyperarithmetic degrees are often more tractable than the Turing degrees, and in particular they're known to be rigid so a negative answer to "Q2$^{hyp}$" might be accessible)*, although my primary interest is in the Turing degrees.

Comment: You might consider associating the partial order of the Turing degrees below d, D(<= d), with the degree d.  I would guess that standard coding methods should be sufficient to show that there is no cone of degrees d such that their D(<= d) have a common isomorphism type.

Comment: @TheodoreSlaman Yes, that was the only obstacle I could think of (or any other countable structure associated to a degree in a reasonable way, per my comment after question 1), but I can't immediately see a coding argument for it. That said, I'm not very familiar with those arguments.

Comment: I agree with Ted. Here is an outline: By Shore's result (or 0' is definable, but that asks too much), the collection of arithmertical degrees is definable (without parameters) in D (or D(\leq a) for sufficient large degree a). Notice that  Slaman-Woodin's coding can be performed within arithemtical degrees. Then by (still) Slaman-Woodin's results, for any sufficient large degress c and d with sufficient large gap, D(\leq a) is not isomorphic to D(\leq b) (even more, it cannot be elementary embedded).